# How to get value from Stored Procedure with string return type using JPA?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, stored-procedures

I have a Stored procedure stored in my database and I want to access its return value using JPA or any other function without using query. How can I do it?

Its something like this:

```
 BEGIN                                                                                             
         SELECT prefix ||                                                                      
                 coalesce(to_char(curdt, date_prefix_pattern),'') ||                               
                 trim(to_char(num, num_pattern)) AS id                                             
         INTO rec                                                                                  
         FROM crud_id_patterns                                                                     
         WHERE pattern_id = patternId;                                                             
                                                                                                   
         return rec.id;                                                                            
 END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this @Procedure example may help you

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures

Comment: Yeah! just referred it.Thanks for the tip anyways